# start with Scala, intelliJ IDEA and SBT，sbt download failed

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

[image]

i use Intellij 14.1.2 scala plugin to create scala project,but the SBT downloading is slowly,how can i change this download url or download manually。

Comment: Possible causes: 1. The server is under heavy load -> you can't do anything.  2. You got a bad connection -> try restarting.  3. You have a slow connection -> try moving computer to a faster connection if feasible.

Comment: thanks.i waited long time about 20 minitues.download successfully.